# How Can I Make QGIS Stop Blinking Every Time I Pan?

Tags: qgis, rendering, cache

The way QGIS draws the canvas when panning is quite annoying. If I pan the map even a little bit  everything goes blank for a second or two before the layers are drawn. It looks like this happens only when the layer content is supposed to be downloaded (my PostGIS layers are drawn without hurting my eyes), so this might be just a problem with the configuration rather than the code. Does anyone have a solution?

Oh, and the question should be "how  can I make QGIS suitable for epileptics?". It's that annoying.

**EDIT to pose question for QGIS 2.4 onwards:**

This still appears to be an issue in 2.4. There seem to be some helpful setting under *Settings > Rendering* but these don't help the issue. QGIS just lacks the nice, slippy, smooth feel of other map viewers. Is caching still on the cards?

Comment: This is one of biggest pet peeves with Qgis. The problem is really terrible when you have a layer from the OpenLayers Plugin in your map.

Comment: It's not ideal, but you can turn off rendering by ticking the `render` box on the bottom toolbar. This means that data outside the current viewport is no longer shown/refreshed, though.

Comment: it is even more annoying  when you think that the same layers are rendered "correctly" by geoserver and even udig. Alas i cannot turn to them, i need qgis's advanced sql capabilities to test some geo queries

Comment: @orieeel geoserver and udig are done in Java and use a different rendering technique

Comment: In Master you could try Settings -> Options... -> Rendering and ticking "Enable back buffer". Not sure if this is possible in 1.8. N.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who is still having this problem, in QGIS 2.10 you can go to *Settings > Options > Rendering*, and change the *Map update interval* to be larger. If QGIS can render all of the layers in less than this amount of time, it will update the whole canvas at once, which gets rid of the blinking. If it cannot update all the layers before this interval passes, it will show a partial update, which causes the blinking. You can view how long a canvas update takes by enabling the debugging flag in the rendering settings.

Comment: I am digitzing polygons based on a UAV images (1GB raster RGB image) and after updating the polygon, the image reloaded each time. that took about 5 seconds for each polygon! In my case "use render caching" in the same options solved my problem! QGIS 2.10.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid the answer is: You can stop QGIS from blinking by funding a developer to implement a non-blinking version.

Comment: To explain why:  It currently comes down to how the layers and features are rendered in the rendering engine.  There are some future developments, mainly multi-threading, and caching, that should help to reduce this but not fully.

Comment: Underdark : LOL

Comment: @underdark wish i could, but it won't happen from my student budget.

Comment: @nathan-w just tested the landcover raster from qgis demo dataset and there are no panning problems SO i'm pretty sure  the problem appears mainly when the layers are not on localhost

Comment: maybe this problem can be solved by using a server on localhost for caching?...it's just incredible the wms/wfs data that has already been downloaded is not reused..

Comment: @orieeel QGIS doesn't have any caching yet but it is planned.

Comment: did any of the more experienced users try the 3rd party cache approach to workaround the blink-blink? how'd it go? any other viable workaround?

Answer (score 3):

There's an easy "fix" if you're brave enough to change the code source of QGIS:

Open 'qgsmaptoolpan.cpp', and into the corresponding 'canvasMoveEvent' member, add the sentence "mCanvas->refresh();" as follows:

```
void QgsMapToolPan::canvasMoveEvent( QMouseEvent * e )
{
  if (( e->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton ) )
  {
    mDragging = true;
    // move map and other canvas items
    mCanvas->panAction( e );
    mCanvas->refresh();
  }
}
```

(QGIS version 1.8 Lisboa)

This will force a continuous refresh on the map while you are panning with the  mouse. It could go a bit slower, but it works fine, yeah, a relax for my eyes.

Comment: where is that file..? I can't find it in my OpenSuse 12.x
Thanks

Comment: Why the need to modify the source code when can just override the method?

Comment: How would one do that, @sean?

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in QGIS 3.18, the map redraws are now using existing elements: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-smarter-map-redraws